# Black Border on My IOS Icon

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, simulator

I plugged in my application, the icons for the application itself .. 
Unfortunately I have a problem. 
In the Home Screen icon has a black border. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Why in the simulator I see correctly while the icon on the device I can not see properly. 
I am attaching the screen 
thanks, 
Vincenzo

[image: iCon iPhone Simulator] icon iphone simulator

[image: iCon iPhone 5 Device] icon real device

Comment: Which one is your wrong icon. U attached 2 icon but not mentioned

Comment: Size of the icone ? Which device? Same simulated device than the real one? On the simulator, if you change the background, same issue ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You probably can't see it on the simulator as it has a black background.

I am gonna take a guess and say that you have some transparency in your icon.

Make sure that you icon fills the entire image, you don't need to add the corner radius on yourself either as the OS will do it for you..

Answer (score 5):

I think icons might have transparent border area.. Remove the transparent area.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from [liamnichols's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26016841/6521116)'s transparency border. I find there also other two issues.

**a.** transparency border (as [liamnichols's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26016841/6521116))

**b.** icon has a black border (rare and easy to find)

**c.** icon size is less than the regulation (for example `60 x 60` not match the `87 x 87`)